# How to write to different files in C# from user inputs

Tags: c#, filestream

I need to add the student name and student marks to two different files from the user input. This is my current code. I am atempting to add the user input to an array then add that to the file. It runs as a subroutine, away from my main code and it does not need to return anything to it.

```
    //subroutine to input data and save to a new file 
    public static void SaveToFile()
    {
        BinaryWriter bw;
        string[] studentName;
        int[] studentMark;
        BinaryWriter nameFile;
        BinaryWriter markFile;

        nameFile = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("studentNames.txt", FileMode.Create));
        markFile = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("studentMarks.txt", FileMode.Create));
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a student name and a mark or, END to finish: ");
        while (/*The input*/ != "END")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter student name: ");
            studentName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter mark: ");
            studentMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        bw.Close();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Create a variable for each file, and most importat, assign each one to each BinaryWriter.

Comment: I changed the file names to make them more appropriate and i added the variables

Comment: What is `while (/*The input*/ != "END")` doing?

Comment: It is used to stop the while loop from running when they have finished adding names to the file. However, i don't know how I would code that. I might change it to an IF loop instead and have the IF loop check each input instead

Comment: The `while` will work; however, you need to “check” some variable to see if the user has typed “END.” In this case I will assume you nee to check `studentName` … something like `while (studentName != "END")`. In addition, where is the code “writing” to the files?

Comment: It doesn't like while (studentName != "END") because its an array and not a variable. With regards to writing to the file, I don't know how to do that so I haven't coded that yet. I just want to get this working first before I code that.

Comment: You are right, `studentName` is an array… Then the compiler should be complaining on the line… `studentName = Console.ReadLine();` … You will need a `string` for this. Either make `studentName` a string or create a new string variable.

Comment: With the new answer I wont need to but later when i read this code to display it that may be helpful to convert each part of the array to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want the data written as binary or text?
do you want a newline between each value? I added one, you can remove it or change it to anything else..
this will write to each file, however you should add something to check that the grade is really a number (otherwise this could throw an exception)..

```
    public static void SaveToFile()
    {
        string studentName;
        int studentMark;
        BinaryWriter nameFile;
        BinaryWriter markFile;

        nameFile = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("studentNames.txt", FileMode.Create));
        markFile = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("studentMarks.txt", FileMode.Create));
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a student name and a mark or, END to finish: ");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter student name: ");
        studentName = Console.ReadLine();

        while (studentName.ToUpper() != "END")
        {
            nameFile.Write(studentName + Environment.NewLine);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter mark: ");
            studentMark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            markFile.Write(studentMark + Environment.NewLine);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter student name: ");
            studentName = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        nameFile.Close();
        markFile.Close();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I will probably keep the new line between each name/mark so that i can read them individually later on in my code as i need to display this data on screen later with each grade matching up to each student. Also, I will need to calculate the average grade of the marks so new lines should help with that